# Cómo deshabilitar en jquery lunes, martes y domingo

Tags: jquery

Tengo el siguiente codigo en jquery que deshabilita los fines de de semana y muestra 4 días por adelantado y excluyendo los dos primeros días a partir de la fecha actual:

```
jQuery(function($){
  $.datepicker.regional['es'] = {
      closeText: 'Cerrar',
      prevText: '&#x3C;Ant',
      nextText: 'Sig&#x3E;',
      currentText: 'Hoy',
      monthNames: ['enero','febrero','marzo','abril','mayo','junio',
      'julio','agosto','septiembre','octubre','noviembre','diciembre'],
      monthNamesShort: ['ene','feb','mar','abr','may','jun',
      'jul','ago','sep','oct','nov','dic'],
      dayNames: ['domingo','lunes','martes','miércoles','jueves','viernes','sábado'],
      dayNamesShort: ['dom','lun','mar','mié','jue','vie','sáb'],
      dayNamesMin: ['D','L','M','X','J','V','S'],
      weekHeader: 'Sm',
      dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
      firstDay: 1,
      isRTL: false,
      showMonthAfterYear: false,
      yearSuffix: ''};
  $.datepicker.setDefaults($.datepicker.regional['es']);
});

var QuitarFechas = ["6/8/2020", "31/12/2030"];
        
function deshabilitar(date) {
  hoy = date.getDate() + "/" + (date.getMonth()+1) + "/" + date.getFullYear();
  if ($.inArray(hoy, QuitarFechas) < 0) {
     return $.datepicker.noWeekends (date)} 
  else {
     return [false,"","Fecha deshabilitada"];}
  }
  $(function() {
    $('#datepicker').datepicker({ 
        minDate: 2,
        maxDate: '+4d',
        beforeShowDay: deshabilitar
    });                         
  });
```

Lo que si necesitaría ahora es ¿como deshabilitar los lunes, los martes y los domingos y que se muestren unicamente los miercoles, jueves, viernes y sábado?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La función que ya tienes `deshabilitar` puedes modificarla y agregar la condición según el número de día que necesitas habilitar/desabilitar

```js
function deshabilitar (date){
      // Combinar con lógica que ya tienes...
      let diasCerrado = [0,1,2]
      if (diasCerrado.includes(date.getDay()))  
            return [ false, "closed", "No disponible" ]
      else
            return [ true, "", "" ]
}
```

Comment: Funciona perfectamente como quería. Muchas gracias

Comment: Documentación https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getDay

Comment: @Jhon Si la respuesta te ha ayudado, favor marcarla como aceptada. Saludos